# return to index.html from images.html by using phone back button in phonegap android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

i am working on android phonegap, my app has 2 .html pages ,(1) index.html has multiple pages using jquery mobile, i have a link in index.html to (2)images.html, images.html is a simple html page, i want my phone's back button to navigate to index.html's multiple page having its id #page2 when i am on images.html. Any one can plz help me in getting work from (hardware) phone's back button to navigate to index.html#page2, i already have a back button code which is working absolutely fine only in index.html, but how can i make it useable to get back to index.html#page2 from images.html
here is my back button code whick is working for my index.html.....
    // JavaScript Document

```
$("#page2").click(function(){
$.mobile.changePage("#page2");
});
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
// PhoneGap loaded

function onDeviceReady() {
console.log("PhoneGap Ready!");
// waiting for button
document.addEventListener("backbutton", handleBackButton, false);
}

// handle the back button
function handleBackButton() {
console.log("Back Button Pressed!");
if($.mobile.activePage.is('#page2')){
//e.preventDefault();
navigator.app.exitApp();
}
else {
navigator.app.backHistory();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `$.mobile.phonegapNavigationEnabled = true` in your `mobileinit` handler per http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/phonegap.html instructions.

Comment: thanks for your reply, as i am new in android development i don't have any idea where can i do  $.mobile.phonegapNavigationEnabled = true, your little more explanation would make me more clear.......... thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown() {
    // Handle the back button
}
```

Refer [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#backbutton)